# TypeError: Cannot read property 'formModel' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm getting this error when using reactive forms. Here is my code

```
<div [formGroup]="service.formModel" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
    <mat-form-field fxFlex="33%" appearance="outline">
      <mat-label class="label-text">District</mat-label>
      <mat-select formControlName="District">
        <mat-option value="None">None</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let district of districts" [value]="district.value">{{district}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-icon class="icon-color" matSuffix>layers</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field></div>
```

and here is an array of Districs:

component file

```
districts:string[] = [
  'Queensland', 'New South Wales','Australian Capital Territory'];
```

services file!

```
  formModel = this.fb.group({
 District:['']});
```

Why i'm getting this error maybe because district is null or something?

Comment: apparently `Service` is `undefined`, like error suggest. You need to figure out why. Is it correctly injected in constructor? Also like mentioned it should be `[formGroup]` and not `[FormGroup]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using `Service` which is null directly in the HTML.

If it is indeed a service (correctly defined in your constructor), then define `formModel` in your `ngOnInit` for example in your component:

```
formModel: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.formModel = this.service.getFormModel();
}
```

and in your HTML:

```
<div [formGroup]="formModel" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
```

And in your service:

```
getFormModel(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    District:['']
  });
}
```

Comment: in services i have to define in ngOnInit?

Comment: got another error... Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error, code should be like this -

```
<div [formGroup]="formModel" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
.....
```

- `FormGroup` should be `formGroup`
- Binding with formgroup should be `formModel` instead of `Service.formModel`

Comment: formModel is in service  so i have to user Service.formModel

Comment: Oh, okay then `formGroup` syntax should be correct as I suggested